# Can I enable typescript processing only on TS files in wro4j?

Tags: java, typescript, wro4j

I have a legacy app with has old JS code, but I want to utilize TypeScript for some of the newer components.  Is it possible to tell wro4j to only apply the **rhinoTypeScript** preprocessor only on "*.ts" files?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: no I have not been able to.  I just removed the TS components and put it on a separate project.

Comment: well, ok, thanks anyway. In fact I'd like to migrate away from wro4j, but we have a lot of code that depends on it ...

Comment: TBH, WRO4J isn't bad, its good for JSP based applications and I'll still likely use it.  It's only if you want to migrate away from a Java EE app that hosts pages.